# Silverlight tab header in the left buttom

Tags: silverlight, controltemplate

I  used TabStripPlacement="Left" and it made the header in the left side, but I also want them to be in the bottom, How do I do that ?

[image]

XAML:

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Primitives:TabPanel">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <sdk:TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" x:Name="MainTabControl" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <sdk:TabControl.Items>
            <sdk:TabItem Header="File 1"/>
            <sdk:TabItem Header="File 2"/>
            <sdk:TabItem Header="File 3"/>
            <sdk:TabItem Header="File 4"/>
        </sdk:TabControl.Items>
    </sdk:TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by setting VerticalAlignment="Buttom" in the TabControl template style, on the TabPanel object in the left section.